# How to get path of a Folder and use with StreamWriter?

Tags: c#

Folder path. Here's my current codes:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Username = Nametxt.Text;
        var directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E"));
        directoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory(Username); // Create a Sub-Folder inside "F.U.T.U.R.E"

        StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Username + ".txt");  
        stream.WriteLine(passwordtxt.Text);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

From the current codes the text is being created in the software directory`@`.

Part 1:
On button click the software should create a folder entitle "F.U.T.U.R.E" then create a Sub-Folder with the Name`String Username= textbox1.text`.

Part2:
Creating a `new StreamWriter`inside the new Sub-Folder `Username`

Comment: "So here's the trouble am having" Hm you are not saying what trouble you are having! What does not work?

Comment: StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E", Username)) + Username + ".txt")

This is not working ^

Comment: What about that? Why is it not working? What happens?

Comment: It's causing errors http://i.imgur.com/Mmwe6En.png In the whole line code.

Comment: Do you want to first create a new folder and than create a new text file in that folder ?

Comment: Here's a tip: You should **read** what the errors says because it usually tells you what's wrong.

Comment: You have misplaced parantheses.

Comment: I have one bracket too much :(

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin If you don't want downvotes - provide all necessary details in the post in readable form - error messages, [MCVE], expected behavior. Note that SO is trying to provide answers usable for future readers - post in the current state can't be useful to anyone but OP - and this is somewhat selfish behavior from OP.

Comment: @AlexeilLevenkov Sorry Ive correct my question , you may have a look . Its just difficult for me to express myself but FarhanAnam got understood my question. Ill try my best to not commit mistake in the Future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the full path of the file in the constructor of the `StreamWriter`:

```
String Username = Nametxt.Text;
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E")).CreateSubdirectory(Username);
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, Username + ".txt"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass the full path, such as

```
 StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E", Username) + Username + ".txt")
```

Comment: What is the error? Updated my answer as I had a bracket too  much.

Comment: Bad luck. One bracket was too heavy.. :). +1 from me though.

Comment: Same from me xD Thanks @Farhan